# Knitr: how to update chunk options?

Tags: r, knitr

I would like to add a chunk option, say `add_graph`, that, if `TRUE`, appends a string `LINK` to the figure caption. (Really, a want to use the LaTeX attachfile package to include a separate copy of the graph within the caption thereof.) Based on an example from the Knitr book, I thought the following could work, but it doesn't.

```
hook_plot <- knit_hooks$get('plot')
knit_hooks$set(plot=function(x, options){
   if(!is.null(cap <- options$fig.cap)){
      if(options$add_graph){
         opts_chunk$set(fig.cap = paste(cap, "LINK."))
      }
   }
   hook_plot(x, options)
})
```

A subsequent chunk with chunk option `add_graph=TRUE` and a `fig.cap` does produce a plot, but nothing is appended to the caption.

Comment: To start with, your hook function needs to take three arguments, `before`, `options`, and `envir`, [as mentioned almost immediately here](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks).

Comment: @Josh O'Brien  - That is true of 'chunk hooks', but not of 'output hooks' (which are described further down that page).